# What is the fastest algorithm for multiplication of two n-digit numbers?

Tags: algorithm

I am aware that computers use the shift and add method to multiply two numbers.

The bit wise shift multiplies and divides by the powers of two. This operation is faster than a multiply instruction.
Multiplication by a constant and division by a constant can be implemented using a sequence of shifts and adds or subtracts.

```
((x << 2) + x) << 1 // Here 10*x is computed as (x*2^2 + x)*2
(x << 3) + (x << 1) // Here 10*x is computed as x*2^3 + x*2
```

But is there a faster algorithm to do so?

*Thx for the help :)*

Comment: If you have a decent compiler, `10*x` will be the fastest algorithm.

Comment: @stefan I agree. Compiler will optimise

Comment: This isn't multiplication of two n-bit numbers though. It's multiplication by a constant, so it's not hard to get O(n) (and clearly you can do no better). So what are you really looking for? Something like Schönhage–Strassen or something that looks like the code from your question?

Comment: On a fairly modern CPU, g++ compiles `10 * x` to the exact same thing as your first shift expression: `leal (%rdi,%rdi,4), %eax addl %eax, %eax`

Comment: Use a profiler and see for yourself. Which is faster is highly subjective and dependent on many external factors. The only way to know for sure is to test in the environments you're targeting. However, unless this is purely an academic exercise, it screams of micro-optimization. Unless, you're going to be targeting an extremely resource constrained device, it's unlikely either method is significantly faster to warrant doing anything but using the method that's easiest to read and maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers use whatever combination of native assembly instructions is most efficient.

When multiplying by a constant, compilers will choose direct multiplication or shifts based on the number of cycles and binary code size each strategy costs. It's typically a job for low level optimizer, that requires exact knowledge of the processor the code is running on.

You won't beat a compiler at this game.

Answer (score 3):

For really large `n`s (>1000 digits roughly), there are specialised algorithms, in increasing order of strength they are: [Karatsuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), [Toom-Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) and finally the monster of 100000 digit multiplications: [Schönhage-Strassen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm).

These perform poorly on smaller numbers due to their overheads but asymptotically they're far better than naive multiplication.

Comment: thanks for those examples

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm